# In Word2Vec, how to the vector values translate back to related words?

Tags: word2vec

Apologies for the newbie question: I've just downloadd the GoogleNews word2vec bin file and used convertvec to convert it to a text file to look at the vector values. I see they are values between -1 and 1. Can somebody explain how these values map back to related terms?

I would eventually like to write some code to take this bin/text file, transform it and load it into a MongoDB database for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) in Python, you can create a dictionary with the word and the vector.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# we create a Word2Vec model using a window size of 4 and word vectors dimensionality of 100
model_1 = Word2Vec(window=4,size=100,sg=1,min_count=1, workers = -1)
# prepare the model vocabulary
model_1.build_vocab(this_is_your_text_dataset)
# train the model
model_1.train(this_is_your_text_dataset,total_examples=model_1.corpus_count,epochs=model_1.iter)

#we create a dictionary with the word and its vector as the value
vectors_model = dict(zip(model_1.wv.index2word, model_1.wv.syn0))
```

The above will create a dictionary in the format:

```
{
"word_1": vector_1,
"word_2": vector_2,
"word_3": vector_3,
....
}
```

With this, you can go back and forth from words to vectors and from vectors to words.